# error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to debug some homework but I am having trouble with these lines of code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   char word;
   cout << "Enter a word and I will tell you whether it is" << endl <<
 "in the first or last half of the alphabet." << endl << 
   "Please begin the word with a lowercase letter. --> ";
   cin >> word;
   if(word[0] >= 'm')
     cout << word << " is in the first half of the alphabet" << endl;
   else
     cout << word << " is in the last half of the alphabet" << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

I get the following error and I have no clue what its sayings

```
error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another suggestion:  declare output text as one entity, then block write.  This may make your programs easier to debug, read and understand.

```
int main(void)
{
    static const char prompt[] =
    "Enter a word and I will tell you whether it is\n"
    "in the first or last half of the alphabet.\n"
    "Please begin the word with a lowercase letter. --> ";

   string word;
   cout.write(prompt, sizeof(prompt) - sizeof('\0'));

   getline(cin, word);

   cout << word;
   cout << "is in the ";
   if(word[0] >= 'm')
     cout "first";
   else
     cout << "last";

   cout << " half of the alphabet\n";
   return 0;
}
```

For Your Information (FYI):

1. `stdafx.h` is not a standard header
   and not required for small projects.
2. `conio.h` is not a standard header
   and not required for simple console
   I/O.
3. Prefer `string` for text rather than
   `char *`.

Answer (score 9):

The term *subscript* refers to the application of `[]` operator. In your `word[0]`, the `[0]` part is a subscript.

The built-in `[]` operator can only be used with arrays or pointers. You are trying to use it with an object of type `char` (your `word` is declared as `char`), which is neither an array nor a pointer. This is what the compiler is telling you.

Comment: Ohhh, what throws me off is I was told that a char is an array of characters. So I thought I would be able to individualy access those characters regardless if I declared varible as an array or not.

Comment: @numerical25: you really ought to read at least one good book on C and/or C++ programming, otherwise you're constantly going to be running into minor problems like this caused by a lack of basic knowledge of the language(s) in question.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
char word;
```

declare

```
string word;
```

You already included the string-class header. Then you can access the elements with the []-operator.

Additional remark: Why do you use conio.h? It is obsolete and is not part of the C++ standard.

Comment: Alternately, he could change the test to `if (word >= 'm')`; that is, lose the subscript.

Comment: @John: I think he wants to output the whole word inside the if-statement and not just the first letter.

Answer (score 0):

word is declared as a `char`, not an array. But you're using `word[0]`.